# Generation random number for the text entered in the textbox

Tags: asp.net

I have a textbox,when a user enters any number(say 3) in the textbox, that many random numbers should be generated.This is what I have done so far but its generating the same random number for all 3(or as many as the user enters) records.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (Int32 x = 0; x <= 50; x++)
        {
            txtRandomNumber.Text = GetRandomString(x);

        }

    }
    public string GetRandomString(int seed)
    {

        const string alphabet = "R";


        Random rnd = new Random((seed + DateTime.Now.Millisecond));


        string result = rnd.Next(10000, 99999).ToString();



        string alpha = alphabet.Substring(rnd.Next(alphabet.Length - 1));


        int replacementIndex = rnd.Next(0);
        result = result.Remove(replacementIndex, 1).Insert(replacementIndex, alpha);


        return result;
    }

    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= int.Parse(txtNoOfPin.Text); i++)
        {
            if (i == 1)
            {
                string strConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ReliableLife"].ToString();
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
                string sqlQuery = "insert into AllotPin(NoOfPin,PinNumber) values(@NoOfPin,@PinNumber)";
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NoOfPin", int.Parse(txtNoOfPin.Text));

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PinNumber", txtRandomNumber.Text);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            else
            {
                string r_no = "";

                for (Int32 x = 0; x <= 50; x++)
                {
                    r_no = GetRandomString(x);
                    //Response.Write(GetRandomString(x) + "<br />");
                }


                string strConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ReliableLife"].ToString();
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
                string sqlQuery = "insert into AllotPin(NoOfPin,PinNumber) values(@NoOfPin,@PinNumber)";
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NoOfPin", int.Parse(txtNoOfPin.Text));

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PinNumber", txtRandomNumber.Text);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }
    }
```

Please Help,Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to apped random number to textbox

```
for (Int32 x = 0; x <= 50; x++)
{
    txtRandomNumber.Text  = x +" "+ GetRandomString(x) +" "+ txtRandomNumber.Text;
}
```

The program has some redundancy but it will generate random numbers as per your requirement.

Comment: still the same random number is getting generated

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.
I solved the problem doing this in the else part of the code:

```
for (Int32 x = 0; x <= 50; x++)
                {
                    r_no = GetRandomString(x);
                    txtRandomNumber.Text = r_no;

                }
```

This gave the output as required.